# How to fix -bash: alias: vim: not found error?

Tags: bash

I am trying to install OpenCV using the follow [tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/19/install-opencv-3-on-macos-with-homebrew-the-easy-way/). One of the steps involves the command: `source ~/.bash_profile`. Running this command gives me the following error:

```
-bash: alias: vim: not found
-bash: alias: =: not found
-bash: alias: vim -S ~/.vimrc: not found
```

I have tried to find a solution online but haven't found any related questions. How do I solve this?

Comment: What's in your `.bash_profile` file?

Answer (score 3):

You appear to have something like

```
alias vim = "vim -S ~/.vimrc"
```

in your `.bash_profile`, which is interpreted as a request to show the definitions for three different aliases. You need to remove the whitespace, with something like

```
alias vim="vim -S ~/.vimrc"
```

Comment: ... none of which has anything to do with vim, OpenCV, or the tutorial linked to by OP.

Comment: None of that sounded particularly relevant, unless the installer is the thing breaking `.bash_profile`. The reported errors are consistent with running a command like I showed at the top.